# How to call from outside a hook in a component included by another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very basic react component like this

```
const Message = (props) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    return (
        <p show={show}>My Message</p>
    );
};
```

I want to use this component from another one, and I want to be able to show the first one by clicking on a button in the second one

```
const OtherComponent = (props) => {
    
    return (
      <>
        <Message />
        <Button onClick={setShow(true)}>Open Message</Button>
      </>
    );
};
```

of course this code does not work, is there a way to achieve this or is Redux my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move state to parent

```
const Message = ({ show }) => {
    return (
        <p show={show}>My Message</p>
    );
};
```

```
const OtherComponent = (props) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    return (
      <>
        <Message show={show} />
        <Button onClick={setShow(true)}>Open Message</Button>
      </>
    );
};
```